# How to restore xfce4 after "accidentally" running "sudo startxfce4"?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, login, lightdm, xfce

Today I was fiddling around with the video settings to get rid of the tearing, and at some point I wanted to restart xfce without restarting the machine.
So I ran "sudo startxfce4" and I saw something is going wrong then I've restarted the PC and now I can't login, I've stuck in a login loop.
After typing in the password on the login screen, lightdm shows some sort of error message for a moment and then the screen goes black, and comes back with the login screen again.
Could anyone direct me to the right direction to fix this big mistake? Thanks.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but could it be that some files in your home directory are now owned by root, and thus inaccessible to you? That can easily be fixed with `sudo chown -R you /home/you`.

Comment: Um.. I can see now that .dbug, .gvfs, .ICEauthority are all owned by root. But I'm not sure if they have to be owned by my username.

Comment: Everything in your home directory should be owned by you.

Comment: this one fixed it, thanks. So the answer is the command what you mentioned in your first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a command with `sudo`, it does not change the value of the `HOME` environment variable:

```
firas@wakaba ~ % sudo env | grep HOME
HOME=/home/firas
```

This means that if the program you are running needs to access files in the user's home directory, it will use your home directory. However, it will still be running with root privileges, so any files it creates will be owned by root. This is a problem, because if you subsequently run the same program with your user privileges, the files created as root may not be accessible to you. Fortunately, the fix is simple: because your home directory and everything it contains is normally owned by you, in normal circumstances you just need to do

```
sudo chown -R username /home/username
```

to restore the correct permission. If for some reason you need to have files owned by other users in your home directory, the responsibility is on you to know what they are and restore ownerships accordingly.

By the way, if you want to run a program with `sudo` and change the `HOME` environment variable to the home directory of the target user, just use the `-H` flag: `sudo -H program`. To make this permanent, set the `always_set_home` flag in your sudoers file.